# Primitive elements of a tensor product of bialgebras

Tags: hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Given a field $k$ of characteristic $0$. For every $k$-bialgebra $A$, let $\mathrm{Prim} A$ denote the $k$-vector subspace of $A$ consisting of all primitive elements of $A$.

What conditions can we put on two $k$-bialgebras $A$ and $B$ to ensure that $\mathrm{Prim}\left(A\otimes B\right) = k\otimes \left(\mathrm{Prim}A\right) + \left(\mathrm{Prim} B\right)\otimes k$ ?

I haven't given this much thought, but I am not good at constructing counterexamples and it seems pointless to try proving anything here before having an "upper bound" on how far we can go. The only results I know about is that $k\otimes \left(\mathrm{Prim}A\right) + \left(\mathrm{Prim} B\right) \otimes k \subseteq \mathrm{Prim}\left(A\otimes B\right)$ always holds (for trivial reasons), and that if $A$ and $B$ are two connected graded cocommutative bialgebras, then $\mathrm{Prim}\left(A\otimes B\right) = k\otimes \left(\mathrm{Prim}A\right) + \left(\mathrm{Prim} B\right)\otimes k$ (as a consequence of Cartier-Milnor-Moore and Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt).

It sounds rather natural to assume $A$ and $B$ to be cocommutative (after all, $\mathrm{Prim} A$ is always $=\mathrm{Prim}\left(A^c\right)$, where $A^c$ the greatest cocommutative sub-bialgebra of $A$), but I am not sure whether we can WLOG assume this to be so (maybe $\left(A\otimes B\right)^c$ is greater than $A^c\otimes B^c$ ?).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well first when we restrict to the case when $A, B$ are filtered (see Bourbaki for example), in this case $\log_{*}$ always converges at $Id$ (as $Id=e+I_+$, $e$ being the unit for the convolution, it suffices to remark that $I_+^{*N}(h)=0$ for $N=N(h)$ large enough).

Now, in the general case, you can adapt the following computation to the algebra $H(A\otimes B)$ generated by the primitive elements of $A\otimes B$ where the series of $\log_{*_{12}}$ always converges.

For clarity, I note $A=A_1,B=A_2$ and and $e_i=1_{A_i}\circ \epsilon_i$.

Then
$$
\log_{*_{12}}(I_1\otimes I_2)=\log_{*_{12}}((I_1\otimes e_2)*_{12}(e_1\otimes I_2))=
$$
$$
\log_{*_{12}}(I_1\otimes e_2)+\log_{*_{12}}(e_1\otimes I_2)
$$
as the two terms $(I_1\otimes e_2), (e_1\otimes I_2)$ commute. Now 
$\log_{*_{12}}(I_1\otimes e_2)=\log_{*_{1}}(I_1)\otimes e_2$ and 
$\log_{*_{12}}(e_1\otimes I_2)=e_1\otimes\log_{*_{2}}(I_2)$.

Which, in view of $\left(\mathrm{Prim}A_1\right) \otimes k + k \otimes \left(\mathrm{Prim} A_2\right) \subseteq \mathrm{Prim}\left(A_1\otimes A_2\right)$, proves that $Prim(A_1\otimes A_2)=Prim(A_1)\otimes k+k\otimes Prim(A_2)$.

Which does your job.

**Addition** : *To answer your first question*, $I_1$ and $e_2$ are morphisms of bialgebras so $I_1\otimes e_2$ maps $Prim(A_1\otimes A_2)$ into $Prim(A_1\otimes A_2)$ and then $H$ into $H$ (in fact the image of  $H(A_1\otimes A_2)$ is a subbialgebra of $H(A_1)\otimes k.1_{A_2}$).

*To answer the second point.* For a bialgebra let us denote $I^+=Id-e$ (the complement projector of $e$) and $H(?)$ the subalgebra generated by the primitive elements. One has, with the morphism of bialgebras
$$
(I_1\otimes e_2) : H(A_1\otimes A_2) \rightarrow H(A_1)\otimes k.1_{A_2} 
$$ 
the intertwining 
$$
(I_1^+\otimes e_2)\circ (I_1\otimes e_2)=(I_1\otimes e_2)\circ (I_1\otimes I_2)^+
$$
so, using series, we get 
$$
(\log_{*_1}(I_1)\otimes e_2)\circ (I_1\otimes e_2)=(I_1\otimes e_2)\circ \log_{*_{12}}(I_1\otimes I_2)
$$
This is because, as a general principle, the intertwining intertwines the convolution. Let, 
$$
\begin{matrix} 
A & \stackrel{\varphi}{\longrightarrow} & B \cr
\downarrow && \downarrow \cr
A & \stackrel{\varphi}{\longrightarrow} & B 
\end{matrix}
$$
with $\varphi$ a morphism of bialgebras and the down arrows $f,g$ such that $g\varphi=\varphi f$. Then, if the bialgebras are generated by primitive elements, if $f(1_A)=0,g(1_B)=0$ and if $S\in k[[x]]$ is a series, we have $S(g)\varphi=\varphi S(f)$. This is not difficult and argued in details (in particular the notion of summability and substitution) in my paper.

In conclusion, I think that
$$
Prim(A_1\otimes A_2)=Prim(A_1)\otimes k.1_{A_2}+k.1_{A_1}\otimes Prim(A_2)
$$ 
is true in full generality. One even does not have to suppose that $k$ is a field, only $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq k$ seems to be needed.

Do not hesitate to question and comment if something is unclear or wrong.

Regards

Comment: This is a nice argument handling a multitude of cases; thanks a lot. I am not sure about its generality, though. How do we know that $I_1\otimes e_2$ is well-defined as an endomorphism of the subalgebra of $A\otimes B$ generated by the primitives? How do we know that $\log_{*_1}\left(I_1\right) \otimes e_2$ projects onto $Prim\left(A_1\right)\otimes k$ (without having $A_1$ cocommutative to begin with)?

Comment: The idea is to restrict to the algebra $H$ generated by the primitive elements of $A\otimes B$ (I do not now is this has a name in general). This algebra is automativally cocommutative. For details, you can have a look at my recent paper 
http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/index.php?halsid=lvv1kumrubiid20li92n3minh5&view_this_doc=hal-00793118&version=2
In order to know the degree of generality, the point is to examine in detail the "domains of convergence" of the elements of the aforementioned computation. 
For example, $\log_{∗_1}(I_1)\otimes e_2$ projects onto $Prim(A_1)\otimes k$, from $H$.

Comment: Ah!! Very nice proof. (You forgot an $I_1$ in $(\log_{*_1}\otimes e_2)\circ (I_1\otimes e_2)=(I_1\otimes e_2)\circ \log_{*_{12}}(I_1\otimes I_2)$.) The paper you are talking about, is it http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00793118 ? Because the link doesn't work for me.

Comment: (Also, the statement "in fact the image of [...]") is slightly wrong.)

Comment: Yes it is this paper. As we aim at coefficients which are rings of function spaces, we had to revisit the theorem of Cartier-Milnor-Moore without PBW (because it is not assumed that Prim(B) has a linear basis). It turns out that only the fact that the ring contains the rationals is needed.   

Comment: (Also, the statement "in fact the image of [...]") is slightly wrong.)

I correct it ! sorry

Comment: I'm glad that Cartier-Milnor-Moore over $\mathbb Q$-algebras has been written up; it has been floating around in the folklore for way too long. But one remark: Over a commutative $\mathbb Q$-algebra, every Lie algebra satisfies PBW. See, for example, the proof cited in http://mathoverflow.net/questions/66683 .

Comment: (One question about your paper, which I hope to find time to delve into during the next weeks: What is a transcendence basis of a noncommutative algebra? (as in Lemma 8))

Comment: In particular for the stuffle product. 

Comment: In p45 of [1], P. E. and al. assume that the ring of scalars is a field of characteristic 0. But, although I have, for the time being, no "natural" counterexample, I cannot restrict to fields because, "my" scalars will be either rings of analytic functions (where inversion creates poles) or arithmetic functions. So, I was obliged to redo the CQMM theorem without supposing any basis. 
I thank you for the reference [1] that I'll add in the further versions of my paper. 
[1] Pavel Etingof et al. Quantum Fields and Strings: A Course for Mathematicians – Duchamp Gérard H. E. 7 hours ago

Comment: About the $\phi$-stuffle: I didn't see the condition that $\phi$ be commutative... is it a standing assumption?

Comment: About [1]: The proof given in [1] only uses that the ground ring is a commutative $\mathbb Q$-algebra (field or not). An alternative proof is given in Emanuela Petracci's thesis http://www.iecn.u-nancy.fr/~petracci/tesi.pdf chapter 2. (I have checked both of the proofs, though I had to insert a lot of steps in the one given in [1], and replace a certain trick I don't understand by an induction in Petracci's thesis. It seems nobody has the time to write detailed proofs these days.)

Comment: Also, Higgins gave another proof (see Theorem 7 (ii) in his "Baer Invariants and the Birkhoff-Witt theorem", http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869369900866 ). I cannot vow for that one because I still haven't read the paper *blush*.

Comment: Finally, there is a proof by P. M. Cohn; see the discussion on 
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/61954 . Unfortunately it is very indirect and (IMHO) hard to understand.

Comment: (As far as I can judge from the first few pages of Higgins' paper, it's by far the most readable of these four sources.)

Comment: Dear Darij, 

Thank you for your remarks and comments. "I didn't see the condition that   be commutative... is it a standing assumption" No, I'll fix this. I think (and hope !) that the section about the CQMM is the most stable (I had to put this paper a bit in a hurry because this section was an answer about a question with the algebraists). I go across the references you give but I suspect that $Prim(B)$ be linearly free everytime.  

I have the counterexample where $Prim(B)$ is NOT linearly free (it is a bit artficial). I check it and put it quickly. Thanks again

Comment: The (counter) example I was speaking about is the following with $A=k[x]$ ($k$
is a field of characteristic zero). Let $Y$ be an alphabet and $A<Y>$
be the usual free algebra (the space of non-commutative polynomials
over $Y$) and $\epsilon$, the "constant term" linear form. Let $conc$
be the concatenation and $\Delta$ the unshuffling. Then
$(A<Y>,conc,1,\Delta,\epsilon)$ is a Hopf algebras (it is the
enveloping algebra of the Lie polynomials). Let $A_+<Y>=ker(\epsilon)$
and $J_N=x^N.A_+<Y>$ then, for $N\geq 1$, $J_N$ is a Hopf ideal and
$Prim(A<Y>/(J_N))$ is never free (no basis). 

Comment: I think that you can rather safely add to you list of on mathoverflow.net/questions/61954
"k is a $Q$-algebra" as one can apply the symmetrisors above to the case of enveloping algebras.

Comment: Cannot one edit the comments ? I have a few typos that I would like to fix !

Comment: "What is a transcendence basis of a noncommutative algebra? (as in Lemma 8))" -> in fact, when ϕ is commutative, the deformation $(\mathbb{Q}<Y>,stuffle_\phi)$ is so. I will make this more clear. 

Comment: I think the counterexample is not a counterexample. See my email for details.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thanks for your edits !

Answer (score 11):

Hi Darij, Hi Gérard,

Here is an elementary proof of $Prim(A \otimes B)=Prim(A)\otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes Prim(B)$, using the counities $\epsilon_A$ and $\epsilon_B$.

Let $X$ be a primitive element of $A \otimes B$. It can be written as :

**(1)** $X=\lambda 1_A \otimes 1_B+x\otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes y+ \sum x_i \otimes y_i$,

with $\epsilon_A(x)=\epsilon_B(y)=\epsilon_A(x_i)=\epsilon_B(y_i)=0$. Then
$\Delta(X)=\lambda 1_A \otimes 1_B\otimes 1_A \otimes 1_B+x^{(1)}\otimes 1_B \otimes x^{(2)}\otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes y^{(1)}\otimes 1_A\otimes y^{(2)}$
$+\sum x_i^{(1)}\otimes y_i^{(1)}\otimes x_i^{(2)}\otimes y_i^{(2)}$ (we are using Sweedler notation, with $z^{(1)} \otimes z^{(2)}$ standing for $\Delta(z)$). Compared with $\Delta(X)=X\otimes 1_A \otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes 1_B \otimes X$, this becomes

**(2)** $\lambda 1_A \otimes 1_B\otimes 1_A \otimes 1_B+x^{(1)}\otimes 1_B \otimes x^{(2)}\otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes y^{(1)}\otimes 1_A\otimes y^{(2)}$
$+\sum x_i^{(1)}\otimes y_i^{(1)}\otimes x_i^{(2)}\otimes y_i^{(2)}$
$=X\otimes 1_A \otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes 1_B \otimes X$.

Applying $Id \otimes \epsilon_B \otimes \epsilon_A\otimes Id$ gives:
$\lambda 1_A \otimes 1_B+x \otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes y+\sum x_i \otimes y_i$
$=\lambda 1_A \otimes 1_B+x \otimes 1_B+\lambda 1_A\otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes y.$
So $\lambda=0$ and $\sum x_i \otimes y_i=0$ (since $\epsilon_A \otimes \epsilon_B$ annihilates all terms but the $\lambda 1_A \otimes 1_B$ ones). Hence **(2)** simplifies to

**(3)** $x^{(1)}\otimes 1_B \otimes x^{(2)}\otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes y^{(1)}\otimes 1_A\otimes y^{(2)}$
$=X\otimes 1_A \otimes 1_B+1_A \otimes 1_B \otimes X$,

and **(1)** simplifies to $X = x \otimes 1_B + 1_A \otimes y$.

Applying $\epsilon_A\otimes Id \otimes \epsilon_A \otimes Id$ to **(3)** gives:
$y^{(1)}\otimes y^{(2)}=y\otimes 1_B+1_B \otimes y$. So $y$ is primitive.
Applying $Id \otimes \epsilon_B\otimes Id \otimes \epsilon_B$ to **(3)** gives:
$x^{(1)}\otimes x^{(2)}= x\otimes 1_A+1_A\otimes x$. So $x$ is primitive. Finally, $X\in Prim(A)\otimes 1_B+1_A\otimes Prim(B)$.

Comment: Hi Loïc, welcome to MO and thanks for this beautiful and astonishingly elementary proof! (Sorry I can't accept this, since I don't want to unaccept Gérard's theoretical perspective.) I took the liberty to edit it to make it (IMHO) clearer and more structured. I hope I didn't adulterate anything. If you don't like my edits, feel free to go on http://mathoverflow.net/revisions/126362/list , scroll down to version 1 and click "rollback".

Comment: Hi Loïc and Darij, 

I like very much Loïc's proof, not only it is elementary but it proves the claim whatever the characteristic. As a matter of fact, my machinery was devoted to prove CQMM without PBW (which is useful when one has $\Q$-algebras) and not really aimed to Darij's question. Cheers 

Answer (score 4):

There is a short proof in Proposition 2.12 of my paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.02150v1 which works over an arbitrary base ring.