# $U\left(\mathfrak a\right) \otimes_{U\left(\mathfrak a\cap\mathfrak b\right)} U\left(\mathfrak b\right) \cong U\left(\mathfrak a + \mathfrak b\right)$ over a ring containing $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: lie-algebras, hopf-algebras, universal-algebra, pbw-theorems

While the Poincaré-Birkhoff-Witt theorem is usually proven (and sometimes even formulated) for free modules only, it is [known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61954) (see also [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87402)) that it holds for arbitrary modules if the ground ring is a $\mathbb Q$-algebra. I am wondering if a similar generalization holds for the following fact, which I learnt today from Pavel Etingof:

Let $\mathfrak c$ be a Lie algebra. Let $\mathfrak a$ and $\mathfrak b$ be two Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak c$ such that $\mathfrak a + \mathfrak b = \mathfrak c$. Clearly, $\mathfrak a \cap \mathfrak b$ is also a Lie subalgebra of $\mathfrak c$. Now, the map

$U\left(\mathfrak a\right) \otimes_{U\left(\mathfrak a\cap \mathfrak b\right)} U\left(\mathfrak b\right) \to U\left(\mathfrak c\right),$

$\alpha\otimes_{U\left(\mathfrak a\cap \mathfrak b\right)} \beta\mapsto\alpha\beta$

is an isomorphism (not of algebras, but of $\left(U\left(\mathfrak a\right),U\left(\mathfrak b\right)\right)$-bimodules).

This is proven for free modules using PBW and appropriate bases. I had no time to do any research on this.

Comment: When I tried to right-click on the title (while in the list of recent questions) to open the question in a new tab, I was only offered to be shown the TeX source of the formula (MathJax, huh?), so maybe it is NOT a very good idea to have titles consisting of formulas only? I will fix it now, hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For some reason, I had forgotten about this question even as I found the answer long ago.

Yes, the fact holds whenever the ground ring is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra. For the proof, see the First proof of Proposition 2.4.1 in my notes for [Pavel Etingof, 18.747 *Infinite-dimensional Lie Algebras*, Spring term 2012 at MIT](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/%7Egrinberg/algebra/etingof-lie.pdf). (Of course, read "commutative $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra" for "field". In the footnote that gives two proofs for $\sigma$ being an algebra isomorphism, read the second of these two proofs; the first requires the ground ring to be a field.)

More generally, this shows that the fact holds whenever the PBW theorem holds for both $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ (that is, all three canonical maps $\operatorname{PBW}_{\mathfrak{a}} : \operatorname{Sym}\left(\mathfrak{a}\right) \to \operatorname{gr}\left(U \left(\mathfrak{a}\right)\right)$ and $\operatorname{PBW}_{\mathfrak{b}} : \operatorname{Sym}\left(\mathfrak{b}\right) \to \operatorname{gr}\left(U \left(\mathfrak{b}\right)\right)$ and $\operatorname{PBW}_{\mathfrak{c}} : \operatorname{Sym}\left(\mathfrak{c}\right) \to \operatorname{gr}\left(U \left(\mathfrak{c}\right)\right)$ are module isomorphisms). (The proof pretends to also require $\operatorname{PBW}_{\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}}$ to be an isomorphism; but if you dig a little bit deeper, you'll see that $\operatorname{PBW}_{\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{b}}$ merely has to be surjective, which it always is.)

But this is not an "if and only if"! The question of whether the fact holds more generally is still open.

Comment: Thank you for the reference [to my question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/300851/about-enveloping-algebras-of-direct-sums) (+1).

Comment: Is it possible to revive the link to your notes for the Etingof's course?

Comment: Is it the same as [this one](https://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/etingof-lie.pdf)?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: Yes, this is. Fixed!